# When does a weak reference get updated to nil in Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c, pointers, automatic-ref-counting, weak-references

Consider the following two cases:

```
// case 1
NSObject *strongOne = [[NSObject alloc] init];
NSObject * __weak weakOne = strongOne;

if (weakOne) {
    NSLog(@"weakOne is not nil.");
} else {
    NSLog(@"weakOne is nil.");
}

strongOne = nil;

if (weakOne) {
    NSLog(@"weakOne is not nil.");
} else {
    NSLog(@"weakOne is nil.");
}
```

Outputs this:

```
weakOne is not nil.
weakOne is not nil.
```

And

```
// case 2
NSObject *strongOne = [[NSObject alloc] init];
NSObject * __weak weakOne = strongOne;

strongOne = nil;

if (weakOne) {
    NSLog(@"weakOne is not nil.");
} else {
    NSLog(@"weakOne is nil.");
}
```

Outputs this:

```
weakOne is nil.
```

As far as I know, when `strongOne` is deallocated, the weak reference to the same object should be updated to `nil`.

My question: **Why does that only happen in `case 2`?**

Comment: You should also test this with a Release-build instead of Debug. The result could be different ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is because when you get into the if statement with weakOne will increment the retain count in autorelease pool; therefore, the weak pointer will not be zero until the autorelease pool drained.

```
 // Try this
NSObject *strongOne = [[NSObject alloc] init];
NSObject * __weak weakOne = strongOne; //count 1
@autoreleasepool {

    if (weakOne) { 
        NSLog(@"weakOne is not nil."); //count 2
    } else {
        NSLog(@"weakOne is nil.");
    }

    strongOne = nil; // count 1

    if (weakOne) { 
        NSLog(@"weakOne is not nil.");
    } else {
        NSLog(@"weakOne is nil.");
    }

} // count 0, therefore the weakOne become nil

if (weakOne) {
    NSLog(@"weakOne is not nil.");
} else {
    NSLog(@"weakOne is nil.");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> As far as I know, when strongOne is deallocated, the weak reference to
>   the same object should be updated to nil.

That's right. But you're not deallocating the object when you set `strongOne` to nil, you're just changing the pointer. ARC probably calls `autorelease` on the object `strongOne` points to, so the object won't actually be deallocated until later, when the autorelease pool is drained.

> Why does that only happen in case 2?

Looks like ARC sends `release` in that case, so the object is deallocated and your weak reference is updated right away.

Or, it might be that the compiler notices that you never use `strongOne` before setting it to nil, except to assign it to a weak pointer, and so decides not to allocate the object in the first place. Step through that code and see if `strongOne` ever gets a non-nil value.